# updating ListView from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have two classes,HomeActivity and CustomListAdapter.THe HomeActivity class extends an activity and then updates a listview.I am populating the data to the listview using a CustomListAdapter class which extends BaseAsapter.Everything is working fine but i want to load the data in a background task.When i do that,an error comes up.
Here is my implementation of the onPostExecute of the AyncTask class.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HomeActivity Params){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);
                lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, shares));
            }
        });

    }
```

I get an error telling me that i should change the constructor on CustomListAdapter.But when i change it,everything goes downhill.
I have tried this unsuccessfully too

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);
        lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, shares));
```

shares is an arraylist of data from the web service.
Here is the constructor in the CustomListAdapter class

```
 public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

How can go about it?Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: as far as I know you do not need to run your UI code in runOnUiThreas's runnable since it is already inside onPostExecute (onPostExecute runs on UI thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change :

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(HomeActivity Params){
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);
            lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this, shares));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: onPostExecute runs on UI thread so you don't need runOnUiThread() in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

See the below code works for me

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDilaog.dismiss();

        itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(
                        IncidentListActivity.this, Util.arrIncidents);
        gridView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
     }
```

And one more thing, you **don't require** `runOnUiThread` in **onPostExecute** method. You can directly change your listview.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your AsyncTask context to your Adapter , you should put your Activity context which hosts your Listview to your AsyncTask class then use that Context to construct your Adapter.

**Edit** : look at this as an example and onPostExecute by default runs on Ui thread and it doesn't need to define a runOnUiThread

```
public class SyncHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResponseType>{
private Activity activity;
public SyncHandler (Activity activity)
{
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

then in your calling Activity pass the Activity context to your Async class :

```
new SyncHandler(this).execute();
```

Comment: @mungaihkamau what is `onPostExecute(HomeActivity Params)` a bit more info is need. what is HomeActivtiy?

Comment: HomeActivity is the main class dislaying the listbview.Params is just a place holder for a parameter.

Comment: @mungaihkamau and your asynctask is in a different file?

Comment: Thanks Arash,Shani has suggested a simpler way of solving it below.I do appreciate your help all the same.